# How do I search for a string containing today's date/dates in a file using python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
rom pathlib import Path

path = Path('/home/hell/Downloads/hello by Adele/')

search_string = 'completed on "%d/%m/%Y"' #%d/%m/%Y today's date
t=0
for o in path.rglob('*.sql'):
    if o.is_file():
        t= t+1
        text = o.read_text()
        if search_string not in text:
            print(o)
            break
```

**search_string = 'completed on "%d/%m/%Y"'**

the script is to search for a string.."completed on 13/13/2022". I would like to add date to the current date to the search parameter but cant figure out how.

kindly assist and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first get your today's date to string

```
from datetime import datetime
dateText = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

then concat your "search_string"

```
search_string ='completed on '+dateText
```

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dateText = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
>>> search_string ='completed on '+dateText
>>> print(search_string)
completed on 26/09/2022
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `datetime` library, you can get 'today' with

```py
from datetime import date

t = date.today()
```

This will be a `datetime.date` object. You can then display it in whatever format you want with the `.strftime()` method, so you'd have `display_date = t.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`. Your new object display_date will be a string in that format.

Do all of that first in your script, and then have your `search_string = f'completed on {display_date}'`

So in total you will have

```py
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import date

t = date.today()
display_date = t.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

path = Path('/home/hell/Downloads/hello by Adele/')

search_string = f'completed on {display_date}'
t=0
for o in path.rglob('*.sql'):
    if o.is_file():
        t= t+1
        text = o.read_text()
        if search_string not in text:
            print(o)
            break
```